# What does There is an unknown word starting at index 0 means?

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, detailsview

I am trying to bind a gridview to a detailsview in ASP.NET using a SQL Server 2008 database. When I try to bind the detailsview, I get this error message:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown
>   word starting at index 0.

Code:

```
protected void gvstudentworkshop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.dvuserworkshop.Visible = true;
        this.dvuserworkshop.DataBind();
        this.UpdatePanel1.Update();
        this.Modalenroll.Show();
}
```

This is the query I am using:

```
SelectCommand="
SELECT * FROM [tblUserWorkshop] 
WHERE (([WorkshopName] = @WorkshopName) 
AND ([WorkshopLocation] = @WorkshopLocation) 
AND ([UserID] = @UserID) 
AND ([WorkshopDate] = @WorkshopDate))" 

UpdateCommand="
UPDATE [tblUserWorkshop] 
SET [UserWorkshopPaymentStaus] = @UserWorkshopPaymentStaus, 
[ReferralSource] = @ReferralSource, 
[UserWorkshopState] = @UserWorkshopState, 
[UserLastName] = @UserLastName, 
[UserFirstname] = @UserFirstname, 
[UserMiddleInitial] = @UserMiddleInitial 
WHERE [WorkshopName] = @original_WorkshopName 
AND [WorkshopDate] = @original_WorkshopDate 
AND [WorkshopLocation] = @original_WorkshopLocation 
AND [UserID] = @original_UserID 
AND (([UserWorkshopPaymentStaus] = @original_UserWorkshopPaymentStaus) 
OR ([UserWorkshopPaymentStaus] IS NULL 
AND @original_UserWorkshopPaymentStaus IS NULL)) 
AND (([ReferralSource] = @original_ReferralSource) 
OR ([ReferralSource] IS NULL 
AND @original_ReferralSource IS NULL)) 
AND (([UserWorkshopState] = @original_UserWorkshopState) 
OR ([UserWorkshopState] IS NULL 
AND @original_UserWorkshopState IS NULL)) 
AND (([UserLastName] = @original_UserLastName) 
OR ([UserLastName] IS NULL AND @original_UserLastName IS NULL)) 
AND (([UserFirstname] = @original_UserFirstname) 
OR ([UserFirstname] IS NULL 
AND @original_UserFirstname IS NULL)) 
AND (([UserMiddleInitial] = @original_UserMiddleInitial) 
OR ([UserMiddleInitial] IS NULL
 AND @original_UserMiddleInitial IS NULL))">
```

Is there a possible reason why I am getting this error message?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: i guess the format u pass to DB is unrecognized, can you show how is ur date passing? maybe u need to use DateTime.ParseExact() to pass ur date to DB, but still need to check how did u pass ur date =)

Comment: @CheemunLow I'm very new at this. Do you have an example on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bind function seems to be unable to convert the return value from the database to the datetime object. Can you find out the return value of datetime and see if that can be converted to a valid datetime?

Comment: How can I make the conversion using a gridview and a detailsview. Any examples?